VS Code Extension Development - Conditionally hide Extension Settings
I would like to hide my custom settings, which can be found in the settings window of my Extension.
Usually they are configured in package.json like this:
"contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "My Extension",
            "properties": {
                "myExt.SomeSettings": {
                    "scope": "resource",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "This is the description"
                },

What i already tried is setting a custom context key and checking it in a when clause as desribed in here:.
So i added a when clause to my package.json
"contributes": {
        "configuration": {
            "type": "object",
            "title": "My Extension",
            "properties": {
                "myExt.SomeSettings": {
                    "scope": "resource",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": null,
                    "description": "This is the description",
                    "when": "myExt.hideSetting == true"

And in my activate function in extension.ts, i also added the corresponding context key:
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', 'myExt.hideSetting ', true);

When i now start my extension, i still see my Settings in the UI even though the key is set correctly. I checked this using the inspect-context-keys-utility.
Is there a different way to achieve this or is it in general not possible the conditionally hide my custom extension settings?
